# Mousedown event listener for button press not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm building a pong emulator with plain vanilla JavaScript, you can see the code on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/RossCodes/pen/zxPJGM) or [GitHub](https://github.com/ross8/pong).

I want to use key press controls for computers and on screen button presses for mobile devices. I'm having trouble with the onscreen button presses. Starting on line 149 of the script, I am trying to update the value of the `leftButtonPressed` variable with event listeners:

```
//Storing control button presses

var leftButton = document.getElementById('left-button'); //Get left button
var leftButtonPressed = false; //variable to store whether or not the left button is pressed

var leftMouseDown = function(){ //function to update leftButtonPressed
    leftButtonPressed = true;
};

var leftMouseUp = function(){ //funciton to update leftButtonPressed
    leftButtonPressed = false;
};

//Event listeners to see if left button is pressed

leftButton.addEventListener('mousedown',leftMouseDown,false);
leftButton.addEventListener('mouseup',leftMouseUp, false);

//Printing left button press to screen

var buttonPressedText = document.createTextNode(leftButtonPressed);
var buttonPressedTextElement = document.getElementById('button-pressed');
buttonPressedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
buttonPressedTextElement.appendChild(buttonPressedText);
```

Why isn't my `leftButtonPressed` variable being updated?

The following is extra info to understand the context of the script:

I use the following to update my objects and repaint the canvas at 60 fps:

```
//Call step 60 times per second

var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function (callback) { 
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); 
    };
;

//Loop through update, render, animate

var step = function() {
    score();
    update();
    render();
    animate(step);
};
```

As you can see, the portion of the script to update `leftButtonPress` is run every time the player object is updated.

Comment: It looks like you're repeatedly calling `.addEventListener()` in every call to the player "update" method. That will keep adding and re-adding those event handlers over and over again without removing the previously-added event handlers. After a few seconds there will be hundreds and hundreds of copies of each event handler, and all of them will run on each event.

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted to write.. That IS what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, moving the event listeners outside of the update function did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite your HTML also because your git version did not show the buttons.
I changed `<div id="controls" class="visible-xs-block">` to `<div id="controls">` to see the buttons. I changed your JS so that the listeners will only be applied once. Therefore i introduced a `Player.prototype.build = function ()` which is called once. This is a little hack to access the area where you print the state:

```
var self = this;
var leftMouseDown = function(){ //function to update leftButtonPressed
    leftButtonPressed = true;
    self.buttonPressedTextElement.innerHTML = 'pressed';
};

var leftMouseUp = function(){ //funciton to update leftButtonPressed
    leftButtonPressed = false;
    self.buttonPressedTextElement.innerHTML = 'not pressed';
};
```

Changed code Player:

```
function Player() {
   this.build()
   this.paddle = new Paddle(playerStartPositionX, playerStartPositionY);
   this.score = 0;
};
```

new Code Player build:

```
Player.prototype.build = function () {
    //Storing control button presses

    var buttonPressedText = document.createTextNode(leftButtonPressed);
    this.buttonPressedTextElement = document.getElementById('button-pressed');
    this.buttonPressedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
    this.buttonPressedTextElement.appendChild(buttonPressedText);

    var leftButton = document.getElementById('left-button'); //Get left button
    var leftButtonPressed = false; //variable to store whether or not the left button is pressed

    var self = this;
    var leftMouseDown = function(){ //function to update leftButtonPressed
        leftButtonPressed = true;
        self.buttonPressedTextElement.innerHTML = 'pressed';
    };

    var leftMouseUp = function(){ //funciton to update leftButtonPressed
        leftButtonPressed = false;
        self.buttonPressedTextElement.innerHTML = 'not pressed';
    };

    //Event listeners to see if left button is pressed

    leftButton.addEventListener('mousedown',leftMouseDown,false);
    leftButton.addEventListener('mouseup',leftMouseUp, false); 
}
```

new code Player update:

```
 Player.prototype.update = function() {
    for(var key in keysDown) {
        var value = Number(key);
        if(value == 37) { // left arrow pressed
            this.paddle.move(-playerSpeed, 0);
        } else if (value == 39) { // right arrow pressed
            this.paddle.move(playerSpeed, 0);
        } else {
            this.paddle.move(0, 0);
        };
    };
};
```

That does what you want. As i said, applied to the git version